# Test a web application with websockets with multiple separate browsers interacting at the same time

Tags: websocket, karate

I have been using KarateUI to test Spring MVC web applications. It is great for single-user scenarios, or for multiple simulated users taking turns so that they can check that actions of others have taken effect; but I would like to check that some users are notified (via websockets) as soon as other users perform a given action. For example, imagine a web application that includes a game of tic-tac-toe: players are notified via websockets of the actions of their opponents, and so on. Writing a test where users are constantly logging on and off to see the state of the game is possible, but fails to test the real experience.

Is it possible, within KarateUI, to effectively drive 2 or more separate browsers to test such a scenario? Are you aware of other ways of achieving this from external tests (that is, ideally without having to modify the web application itself, so that everything in the application, JS included, can be exercised)?

If, as I suspect, there is nothing easy to use out there that solves my problem, and I decide to try to implement this myself - do you have suggestions for synchronization-aware test-case syntax? I am imagining something like this:

```
 scenario: start multiplayer game in lobby, see new game pop up
    * browser a
    * call read('login.feature@login_a')
    * submit().click("{button}new game")
    * markTime "game created"
    * exists('#game_of_a')

    * browser b
    * call read('login.feature@login_b')
    * submit().click("{button}lobby")
    * var gameExists = exists('#game_of_a')
    * if (gameExists) karate.fail('game should not exist before it is created')       
    * atTime "game created" 
    * delay(1000)
    * exists('#game_of_a')
```

... where you would be able to context-switch between browsers by calling `browser nameOfInstance`, and could synchronize parts of a scenario by marking points-in-time (via `markTime nameOfMark`, which would halt execution until all other browsers in the scenario that mention that time-point (`atTime nameOfMark`) actually reach it. Yes, implementing this may be harder than I think - pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to approach this is to use a normal UI test, but connect to a websocket connection within the same test. Karate has [basic websocket capabilities](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#websocket) so if you are lucky that would suffice. And there is a working example [here](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/blob/2e73fc38e397cf4e46c38b5256c0d91261ea5920/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/websocket/websocket.feature).

Although the example linked above uses an API call to "trigger" the sending of a message from the server, you should be able to do a browser action instead. So the pattern is:

- open a websocket connection
- navigate to the ui and perform an action
- listen for an expected message

This would be much simpler than trying to orchestrate 2 browsers. Even if figuring out how to open a raw websocket connection may be tricky and not a "perfect" simulation of a user doing this within the browser, this may be sufficient for testing that this works.

If you really wanted to go down the path of opening 2 browser windows (tabs are easy with Karate) I recommend using the Java API for one of them, and then calling that from a single Karate feature. Documentation on the Java API can be found [here](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-core/#java-api) - and you can call Java code and possibly have that code spin up the browser on a separate thread etc. Karate cannot have 2 browsers within a `Scenario` which is why you have to delegate to Java.

Finally, I'm confident any complex async case can be handled in Karate once you figure out how to piece things together, refer this example: https://twitter.com/getkarate/status/1417023536082812935

Comment: Thanks for the informative answer - will take a while to test it (will accept if I can get it to work), but so far it is certainly helpful